# Detect language and display proper content

Tags: php, multilingual

I'm working on a multi language website and I'm almost done, except for an annoying detail: the search form displays results for all language.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

I managed to understand that if I put the language prefix (es. **en/** for english) into the form action it will display the current language results.

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>en/">
```

What I need to do now is to replace that **en/** with a PHP code able to detect the current language to put the right prefix in the form action. I could tell the code to read html lang attribute and to echo the proper content, but I don't know how.
Currently this is what I've done:

```
<?php if (get_lang() == 'it-it') {echo "it/";} elseif (get_lang() == 'en-us') {echo "en/";} else {echo "zh/";}?>
```

How do I detect page language in order to modify the form action and display the right content?

Comment: Possibly you can intercept the submit event in JavaScript to modify the action location to include the current lang

Answer (score 3):

Hacking around with **[substr](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)** instead of chained `if else`:

```
echo substr(get_lang(), 0, 2) . "/"; // echo first two characters of get_lang()
```

You can also use **[Locale::getPrimaryLanguage()](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getprimarylanguage.php)**:

```
echo Locale::getPrimaryLanguage(get_lang()) . "/";
```